# Making a scroll view always visible?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

How can I make a scroll view that is always visible, never hiding from a view, in my iPhone app?

Comment: By including punctuation into your sentences.

Comment: > This answer may solve your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345479/uiscrollview-is-unresponsive/12345588#12345588 Hope, will work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After adding the `UIScrollView`, set the property `hidden` to `NO`, so that the scrollview never hides.

```
[myScrollView setHidden:NO];
```

Comment: The hidden property is NO by default. This does nothing. Aside from that, the hidden property just controls whether or not the view is immediately visible at the moment. It doesn't hard lock it so that no one can ever hide it, it just makes it visible if it's hidden.

Comment: i'am Sorry all : i just missed it is the scroll view bar that i want it to be always visible in a text view or in scroll view in my screen

Answer (score 2):

What I understand from your question is that your scroll view is hiding behind some other view. 
you can use [self.view bringSubviewToFront:myScrollView]; when ever you add new view over your scroll view.

and if it is difficult to call bringSubviewToFront: method each time you add another view, you can add your scrollView on appDelegate.Window. I did this for my custom spinner.

Comment: i'am Sorry all : i just missed it is the scroll view bar that i want it to be always visible in a text view or in scroll view in my screen

Answer (score 0):

Simple,

```
[self.view addSubview:myScrollView];
```

Comment: i'am Sorry all : i just missed it is the scroll view bar that i want it to be always visible in a text view or in scroll view in my screen