# UIScrollView is unresponsive

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UIScrollView` inside, all the content is displayed in the scrollview correctly, but for some reason I can't scroll thru it and all buttons are unresponsive.

```
UIScrollView *_scrollView;

_scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
_scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
_scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
_scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
_scrollView.delegate = self;
_scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:_scrollView];


NSInteger yPos = 175;

for(Issue *issue in _dataModel.issues)
{
    // Create some items and add them to the scrollview
    [_scrollView addSubview:tmpItem.view];

    yPos += 140;
}

_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(768, yPos + 50);
```

I set the contentSize correctly, I use the same technique in a different view and there it just works fine.
Not sure if I'm missing something here.

Comment: You havent written setScrollEnabled:YES....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this hope it will solve your issue.

```
scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320, 460)];
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,600)];
[self.view addSubView:scrollView];
```